# How to sequentially read html files without manually opening them one by one?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, html

I have some webpages store as html and everytime I would need click the next file in the  windows explorer.

How can I have the effect like reading picture in irfanview that you scroll the mouse then it would switch to the next page? The htmls were stored in harddisk so loading should be pretty fast and no performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would just open all of them in Opera (Select all in Explorer > open or >open With). Then it's just a mouse gesture (L-shape, down and right) to close one tab and go to the next.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a good approach because I may have 1000 html files. You just can't open 1000 tab at one time.